# Drop down menus are not displaying any values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

My drop down menus are not appearing with any values. What I am trying to achieve is to display the right values in the second drop down menu ("numberDropId") depending on what is selected in the first drop down menu ("optionDrop"). But no values are being displayed in the second drop down menu. I am doing this in Jquery and somebody posted an example of this in JSfiddle and even though his example worked, I cannot get mine to work. Do you know why it is not working an why it is giving me an undefined $ error in my code.

The example Jquery code with the working drop down menus is here [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/pND9u/8/)

My Jquery code is here: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/H58cW/7/)

Comment: You need to load the jQuery framework in the left panel.

Answer (score 0):

You have included `Mootools1.4.1`..see on right side of your fiddle and choose the right framework as `jQuery 1.7`

also on your own page.
include `jQuery` files first and then do all the stuff

Comment: Oh it does work then, I have completly forgot to include to add the neccessary jquery files, I'm a fool. Thanks